# Can't figure out how to cure the "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/junit/internal/AssumptionViolatedException" error

Tags: maven, junit, junit4, powermock, unsupported-class-version

I’m using Java 6, Maven 3.3, JUnit 4.11 and PowerMock 1.6.2.  Although I can run my unit tests properly on my local machine, when I run my tests through Jenkins, I get the following errors …

```
org.mainco.subco.myproject.validator.ResetPasswordValidatorTest  Time elapsed: 2.431 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/junit/internal/AssumptionViolatedException
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
```

Here is the output from Maven dependency:tree …

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] org.mainco.subco:myproject:war:91.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:3.0.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] +- it.sauronsoftware:cron4j:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.mainco.subco:orders:jar:91.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mainco.subco:core:jar:91.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:provided
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:jar:2.0.0.0:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:provided
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.11.RELEASE:compile
```

What dependencies do I need to include/exclude in order to fix the above?

Comment: Are you running it from the IDE or through the console?

Comment: Check whether you have compiled the class you are testing with the same version of java that you are using to run the test.